# How to implement laravel custom carbon timestamp?

Tags: php, laravel, schema, eloquent

I want to have a future timestamp for 'contests' that expire in my table. I can input the time without any problem except when I retrieve the input it doesn't seem to return me a carbon instance but merely a string with the time?

```
public function store(ContestRequest $request)
{
    $input = Request::all();

    // Set the 'owner' attribute to the name of the currently logged in user(obviously requires login)
    $input['owner'] = Auth::user()->name;

    // Set the enddate according to the weeks that the user selected with the input select
    $weeks = Request::input('ends_at');

    // Add the weeks to the current time to set the future expiration date
    $input['ends_at'] = Carbon::now()->addWeeks($weeks);

    Contest::create($input);

    return redirect('contests');
}
```

This is what I am using to create a new contest, the timeformat is exactly the same in the table as the created_at and updated_at fields. They seem to return a Carbon instance when I try something like:

```
$contest->created_at->diffForHumans()
```

Why am I not getting a carbon instance returned?

My migration file looks like this:

```
$table->timestamps();
$table->timestamp('ends_at');
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All you have to do is add it to the `$dates` property in your model.

```
class Contest extends Model {
    protected $dates = ['ends_at'];
}
```

This tells Laravel to treat your `ends_at` attribute the same as it handles `updated_at` and `created_at`

---

@Jakobud You don't have to worry about overriding `created_at` and `updated_at`. They will be merged with the `$dates` array:

```
public function getDates()
{
    $defaults = array(static::CREATED_AT, static::UPDATED_AT);
    return array_merge($this->dates, $defaults);
}
```

`static::CREATED_AT` resolves to `'created_at'` and `static::UPDATED_AT` to `'updated_at'`

Comment: Last I checked, you need to make sure you also include `created_at` and `updated_at` in that array or else you are telling Eloquent to NOT make those date properties.

Comment: Thanks I never knew they would be merged!

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. Does anybody know where this can be found in the docs? I had difficulty trying to backtrace this.

Comment: You're welcome @Stephan-v. It's sort of mentioned in the [soft delete section](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#soft-deleting)

Comment: @lukasgeiter Thanks for pointing there. Expected it here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators - but Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the `getDates()` method, which is responsible for the merge, is not part of stock Laravel. It is part of the [Reliese repo](https://github.com/reliese/laravel).

Answer (score 2):

Laravel only converts it's default timestamps to **Carbon** (`created_at`, `modified_at`). For any other timestamps (such as your `ends_at` column) you could define a property accessor in your `Contest` model:

```
public function getEndsAtAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($value));
}
```

This will convert the `datetime` string returned from the database to a `Carbon` instance when you call `$contest->ends_at`.